# Using multiple datasources with Wildfly

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss, datasource, wildfly

I am using multiple datasources in my java web-application.
Here is Wildfly configuration (standalone mode):

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/DS1" pool-name="DS1" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
   <connection-url>URL1</connection-url>
   <driver>ojdbc7</driver>
   <security>
        <user-name>login</user-name>
        <password>password</password>
   </security>
   <validation>
        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
   </validation>
   <statement>
        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
   </statement>
</datasource>

<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/DS2" pool-name="DS2" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
   <connection-url>URL2</connection-url>
   <driver-class>org.h2.Driver</driver-class>
   <driver>h2</driver>
   <security>
        <user-name>sa</user-name>
        <password>sa</password>
   </security>
   <validation>
        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
   </validation>
   <statement>
         <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
   </statement>
```

Jboss.xml in my ejb subproject:

```
<session>
    <ejb-name>Bean1</ejb-name>
    <resource-description>
        <res-ref-name>DS1</res-ref-name>
        <jndi-name>java:jboss/datasources/DS1</jndi-name>
    </resource-description>
</session>
<session>
    <ejb-name>Bean2</ejb-name>
    <resource-description>
        <res-ref-name>DS2</res-ref-name>
        <jndi-name>java:jboss/datasources/DS2</jndi-name>
    </resource-description>
</session>
```

In EJB Bean1/Bean2 datasources are called via

```
@Resource(name="DS1/DS2")
private DataSource dataSource;

....

Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
```

Using shown configuration I have faced following problems :

1. I can access datasource only if it is set as a default in `<default-bindings>` section of my standalone-full.xml. If it is empty, I get

   `"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies"`

pointing to the list of datasources used in beans during deployment.

2. If I set DS1 as a default one, next time DS2 is injected, it will contain

   `LocalManagedConnectionFactory`

pointing to DS1 in dataSource.mcf variable

As I've understood from this topic
[Why different persistence units with separated data sources query the same data source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279184/why-different-persistence-units-with-separated-data-sources-query-the-same-data)
this problem may be caused by container-managed persistance.

But in given case I am not using any ORM. So I am only able to manipulate datasources using jndi and server configuration.

So is there any way I can resolve this situation by using some additional wildfly configuration / any manipulations with application or I have to use ORM and manage persistance by myself ?

Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 0):

it's recommended to use an ORM (JPA in best case), so you will use entityManager and persitence.xml for using multiple data sources.

```
 <persistence-unit name="DB1_PU">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ds1</jta-data-source>
</persistence-unit>
<persistence-unit name="DB2_PU">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ds2</jta-data-source>
</persistence-unit>
```

and you can call the DS like :

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "DB1_PU")
protected EntityManager entityManager1;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "DB2_PU")
protected EntityManager entityManager2;
```

Comment: you have an typo: persitence.xml -> persi**s**tence.xml